# Returning nested model from backbone via signalr drops attribute property

Tags: backbone.js, model, signalr, fetch

I am working on a backbone/signalr POC. I have very simple models working and I can create them client side and retrieve them via signalr. 
The problem is this:

If I create a client side version of a model with a nested model I can access the attributes like this:

```
model.attributes.nestedModel.attributes.attributeName
```

When I retrieve the model from signalr via

```
model.fetch()
```

the model comes back but now to access the nested model properties I need to use

```
model.attributes.nestedModel.attributeName
```

the attributes level on the nested model is dropped, so this causes template rendering to fail

How do I get around this? Am I doing something wrong? I am new to signalr/backbone.

BTW, I am using the backbone.signalr nuget package.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because when you are using fetch(), the server returns only one JSON object with the model attributes and the attributes of the nested models. for example, the server returns:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "Model",
  nestedModel: {
    id: "12",
    name: "nestedModel"
  }
}
```

backbone is not smart enough to figure out that nestedModel is actually a "model". It treats "nestedModel" as an attribute on Model. (it's just a regular JSON object, not a backbone object)

that's why this:

```
model.attributes.nestedModel.attributes.attributeName
```

does not work.

to make it work, you have to instantiate nestedModel as a Backbone Model. so after fetch is done: (assuming your nestedModel is an instance of NestedModel)

```
model.fetch().done(function() {
  model.set('nestedModel', new NestedModel(model.get('nestedModel')));
});
```

You can make backbone does this for you automatically by overwriting the parse() method.

in your model:

```
var NestedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //your nested model methods
});

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  //do other model stuff

  parse: function(response) {
    response.nestedModel = new NestedModel(response.nestedModel);
    return response;
  }
});
```

this should make your statement work. 
but usually I'd use

```
model.get('nestedModel').get('attributeName')
```

for more info about parse, see here: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse

and to apply this pattern in all other models with more flexibility, you probably wanna read this: 
http://www.devmynd.com/blog/2013-6-backbone-js-with-a-spine-part-2-models-and-collections

Comment: This is awesome thank you. I knew the why, but I wasnt sure what the best way to handle it on the client was. Overriding parse is a great way to handle it.